# Running Pyspark app on Hadoop cluster yields java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, hadoop-yarn

Whenever I run this error shows up:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "~/test-tung/spark_tf.py", line 69, in <module>
    'spark_tf').master('yarn').getOrCreate()
  File "~/main-projects/spark/spark-3.0.0-bin-hadoop3.2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 186, in getOrCreate
  File "~/main-projects/spark/spark-3.0.0-bin-hadoop3.2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/context.py", line 371, in getOrCreate
  File "~/main-projects/spark/spark-3.0.0-bin-hadoop3.2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/context.py", line 131, in __init__
  File "~/main-projects/spark/spark-3.0.0-bin-hadoop3.2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/context.py", line 193, in _do_init
  File "~/main-projects/spark/spark-3.0.0-bin-hadoop3.2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/context.py", line 310, in _initialize_context
  File "~/main-projects/spark/spark-3.0.0-bin-hadoop3.2/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1569, in __call__
  File "~/main-projects/spark/spark-3.0.0-bin-hadoop3.2/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.
: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/spark_project/guava/base/Preconditions
```

A part of my python app `spark_tf.py`:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName(
    'spark_tf').master('yarn').getOrCreate()
model = tf.keras.models.load_model('./model/kdd_binary.h5')
weights = model.get_weights()
config = model.get_config()
bc_weights = spark.sparkContext.broadcast(weights)
bc_config = spark.sparkContext.broadcast(config)
scheme = StructType().add('@timestamp', StringType()).add('@address', StringType())

stream = spark.readStream.format('kafka') \
    .option('kafka.bootstrap.servers', 'my-host:9092') \
    .option('subscribe', 'dltest') \
    .load() \
    .selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)") \
    .select(from_json('value', scheme).alias('json'),
            online_predict('value').alias('result')) \
    .select(to_json(struct('result', 'json.@timestamp', 'json.@address'))
            .alias('value'))


x = stream.writeStream \
    .format('kafka') \
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", 'my-host:9092') \
    .option('topic', 'dlpred') \
    .option('checkpointLocation', './kafka_checkpoint') \
    .start()

x.awaitTermination()
```

My submit line: spark-submit --deploy-mode client --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.0.0 spark_tf.py

I think it's probably because of improper Spark setup but I don't know what caused that.

EDIT: This code I think apparently runs on client instead of Hadoop cluster but running it on the cluster yields the same error.

Comment: Shouldn't you be including guava jar packages in the `--packages` list ?

Comment: I kind of figured it out. I think the code somehow requires the scala 2.11 version of `spark-network-common` while I'm using scala 2.12 Spark (notice `org/spark_project` instead of `org/sparkproject`), to which after I added, some more error showed up, which probably due to bad Spark + Hadoop configuration I think

Comment: spark 3.0.0+ are compiled with scala 2.12 though.

Comment: Yes, I edited my comment that I used 2.12 Spark (3.0.0). I tried to rebuild Spark with Scala 2.12 and proper Hadoop version but the error still showed up.

Comment: I think you're building something incorrectly. Why not download the pre-built Spark version?

Comment: Firstly I used the prebuilt version (spark 3.0.0 with Hadoop 3.2.0) and the error happened so I tried to build one because I thought there was something wrong with the setting.